# ranking based on group in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my post. Apologies in advance, if I am not elaborate in my question.

The requirement is that I need to write SQL statement to achieve the result mentioned in group column.

```
AFE_CD STAGE_NO  LEGEND  GROUP_NO 
40     1         STAGE   1        
40     2         STAGE   1          
40     3         STAGE   1 
40     4         STAGE   1 
40     5         STAGE   1 
40     6         STAGE   1 
40     7         STAGE   1 
40     8         SKIP    2 
40     9         STAGE   3 
40     10        SKIP    4 
40     11        STAGE   5 
40     12        STAGE   5 
40     13        STAGE   5 
40     14        STAGE   5 
40     15        STAGE   5 
40     16        STAGE   5 
50     1         STAGE   6 
50     2         STAGE   6 
50     3         STAGE   6 
50     4         STAGE   6 
50     5         STAGE   6 
50     6         STAGE   6 
50     7         STAGE   6 
50     8         SKIP    7 
50     9         STAGE   8
```

I tried various dense_rank() options but had no luck. One of the failed attempt to write is as below :(.

```
select t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY legend desc ) rnk
from   mytable t
```

mytable contains data as shown above.

Any help/directions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Reformat your question properly, it's unreadable.

Comment: And tell us the answer you would like to get from that data please.

Comment: how are you calculating the value in the last column?  Your question as it stands makes an excellent brain teaser btw

Comment: guys -- the first 3 columns are what he has the 4th column is what he wants.

Comment: Hogan, I was trying to format. Thanks for doing it. I need the last column as result.

Comment: OK, it seems you use the ordering by the first two columns - then you look at the third column and whenever it changes you start a new group. However, it seems that you start a new group also when the value in the first column changes. This is a bit unusual; the more usual arrangement is to start the numbering in column 4 from 1 whenever you switch to another value in column 1, and then you use column 1 and column 4 together for grouping. Please confirm you really need the grouping the way you show it.

Comment: @mathguy - actually this is common.  Thorsten shows the standard pattern to solve it in his answer.

Comment: lol - I just finished writing exactly the same solution. I am still not convinced that this is common though (as a problem statement, not the solution). What I have seen quite often is that groups 6, 7, 8 are actually numbered 1, 2, 3 - and the grouping is by (afe_cd, group_no).

Comment: @Hogan: I am with mathguy here. It would be common to either only detect legend changes for the whole data or to have partitions by afe_cd. But well, this is only slightly different after all.

Comment: @mathguy -- I've seen this as a requirement a lot and then a client "settles" for the other ways because they are easier to implement.  Many people want this.  It is a standard way to think... *"This marker is changing, increment a number"*

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to increment `GROUP_NO` on every `LEGEND` or `AFE_CD` change for the list ordered by `AFE_CD` and `STAGE_NO`. One solution is to detect the changes with `LAG`, having 1 for a change and 0 for no change. And then build a running total of this.

```
select 
  afe_cd, 
  stage_no, 
  legend, 
  sum(is_change) over (order by afe_cd, stage_no) as group_no
from 
(
  select 
    afe_cd, 
    stage_no, 
    legend, 
    case when legend = lag(legend) over (order by afe_cd, stage_no) 
         and  afe_cd = lag(afe_cd) over (order by afe_cd, stage_no) 
      then 0 else 1 end as is_change
  from mytable
)
order by afe_cd, stage_no;
```

Comment: darn it -- I was in the middle or writing this answer when my boss had to come in and ask me about work.  I should stop editing the question to make it readable :D

Comment: @Hogan: Haha, and I spent some time formatting the question only to see that someone else was faster.

Comment: @Hogan: Are you sure it is possible to use group_no in an expression of the the very line I define it? Looks weird.

Comment: I deleted that comment since I was not sure I could use lag like that and I did not have time to test.

Comment: But you are using `lag(legend)` and `lag(afe_cd)` in the line you define them -- so I'm not worred about that part.

Comment: @Hogan: No, `legend` and `afe_ce` are columns that exist. I am creating `is_change` based on them.

Comment: I see what you mean -- that is why the coalesce would be needed so 1 can be added to 0.